# Kernel oops when using netif_rx()

Tags: linux, kernel, driver, ethernet

I am currently developping an ethernet driver for a Linux 3.10.61 on a Texas Instruments Keystone II, armv7l.

I am at the point I want to receive sk_buff to user space.
I have implemented my own polling mode (No interrupts) and I am not using the NAPI so the *netif_receive_skb()*.
My driver is able to receive data but when I try to send my sk_buff to the upper layer with *netif_rx()* the kernel crashes without having the time to display the whole Kernel oops.

`[  624.203739] Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address 00000078
[  624.211818] pgd = c0003000 2014 Oct  2 11:3[  624.214514] [00000078] *pgd=800008000040035:04 147 [  624., *pmd=00000000 
 *******CRASH********`

Does Anyone know why this is happening?
Can this happen because my sk_buff is not well filled?

Thank you for your help,
Sioul

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling netif_rx in a non-softirq context? Perhaps you should use netif_rx_ni instead?
You can refer to the following link:

https://lab.nexedi.cn/kirr/linux/commit/324e786ee39c70ffbdc280c34b7d2b6da5c87879?view=parallel